# I am having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically setup a timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to setup my timeline like so, the issue is wrapping the content since the height will always be different. Willing to use a div format, any code or direction will be helpful.

The picture has an image which has a fixed height makes it hard, but I can use just the circles and draw somehow a vertical line based on the contents height somehow. I moved it up with margin top but it does not look good. and as you can see the text does not move with it.

This is the screenshot [image]

Here is the code for what I tried to do.

```
<div id="container-tbs"> 

  <div id="tb-columns"> 
    <table id="tb-table">
      <tr>
        <td class="tb-left">
          <table>
            <tr class="tb-date-left tb-date"> <td> JUNE 1, 2016 </td></tr>
            <tr class="tb-title-left tb-title"> <td>  TITLE </td></tr>
            <tr class="tb-text-left tb-text"> <td> DESCRIPTIONSSSSS</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> </td> </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
       <td><img class="timeline-pic-left" src="public/i/img/entry-left.png"/> </td>

        <td class="tb-right"></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>

        <td class="tb-left"></td>
       <td><img class="timeline-pic-right" src="public/i/img/entry-right.png"/> </td>
        <td class="tb-right">
          <table>

            <tr class="tb-date-right tb-date"> <td> MAY 1, 2016 </td></tr>

            <tr class="tb-title-right tb-title"> <td>  TITLE </td></tr>
            <tr class="tb-text-right tb-text"> <td> LONG DESCRIPTIONS HERE</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> <img class="tb-pic-right" src="public/i/img/android.png"/> </td> </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  </div>
```

The css:

```
/* tb TABLES */
    #tb-columns {
         margin: 0 auto;
        height: auto; 
        width: auto; 
        max-width:  500px; 
    }
.tb-left {
           vertical-align:top;
        max-width:  250px; 
        height: auto;
    }



 .tb-right {
           vertical-align:top;
        max-width:  250px; 
    }

 .tb-date-left {
        float: right;
        clear:right;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

 .tb-title-left {
        float: right;
        clear:right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .tb-text-left {
        float: right;
        clear:right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: right;
    }



    /* RIGHT SIDE     */
   .tb-date-right {
        float: left;
        clear:left;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .tb-title-right {
        float: left;
        clear:left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .tb-text-right {
        float: left;
        clear:left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }



/* END tb TABLES */
```

I used css for vertically aligning the date and then float the text right and left depending on what side. How do I establish this to wrap the content and have the timeline show different different heigh sizes depending on the content being added dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use "display: flex"  (aka Flexbox) to achieve what you need and grow those boxes without messing up the other ones.

Check this example (taken from Eisneim Terry's):
http://codepen.io/eisneim/pen/goHEr

HTML

```
<h1>Flexbox Timeline</h1>

<ul>
  <li>
    <p>07/2015 - 07/2016</p>
    <p>
      Twitter
      <span>
        Responsibilities: SEO, SEA, E-Mail 
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>07/2014 - 07/2015</p>
    <p>
      Facebook
      <span>
        Responsibilities: HTML5/CSS3, LESS/SASS, jQuery, CanJS, JavaScript, Canvas, PHP, MySQL, Ruby, Python
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>07/2013 - 07/2014</p>
    <p>
      Google
      <span>
        Responsibilities: HTML5/CSS3, LESS/SASS, jQuery, CanJS
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>07/2012 - 07/2013</p>
    <p>
      Apple
      <span>
        Responsibilities: HTML5/CSS3, LESS/SASS
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>07/2011 - 07/2012</p>
    <p>
      Microsoft
      <span>
        Responsibilities: HTML5/CSS3
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 1em/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #999;
}

ul {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

li p {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

li p:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  color: #aaa;
}

li p:nth-child(1):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: -12px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

li:first-child p:nth-child(1):after {
  background: #cfc;
}

li p:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-left: 5px solid #999;
}

li p span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #aaa;
}
```